# Location of saved results in Cplex Optimisation Studio

Tags: cplex, opl

In the CPLEX Optimisation Studio I can [save and restore the results of model solves](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/gsoplide/topics/opl_ide_gs_tut_save_results.html).

I can not find these results in the OPL project directory. Where are those results stored? In the current workspace directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is stored in the history meta data of your workspace. The path to this is something like

```
${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/ilog.odms.ide.core/.history/${PROJECT_NAME}/${RUNCONFIGURATION_NAME}
```

Note that the data stored there may not be human readable. It is designed for consumption by the Optimization Studio IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure that a backup procedure also saved those previous results.